# Solve $\cos^2x - \sin^2x = 0$ for $x\in [0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

How can we find $x\in [0,2\pi]$ such that $\cos^2x - \sin^2x = 0$?

Comment: How about... No?

Comment: Duplicate? I think I recall seeing exactly this question just a few weeks ago.

Comment: @Michael: I saw (and answered) $\cos^2x-\sin^2x=1$ fairly recently.

Comment: Seven answers so far. Are they all equivalent, in the sense that from one identity one could derive all of them? It's late where I live and so I'm not at my best, but my gut feeling is the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint*: $\cos^2x-\sin^2x=0\Leftrightarrow(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)=0$

*Suggestion*: observe the following unit circle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Hint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae):
$\cos x=0\iff x=k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \ k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\cos(x+y)= \cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$

Answer (score 1):

Keeping with the format so far,

*Hint*: $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos^2x - \sin^2x=0 \Rightarrow \cos^2x=\sin^2x\Rightarrow \cos x=\pm \sin x.$

Which angles satisfy the latter?

Answer (score 1):

Use $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v)$ and $ab=0$ iff $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos(2x)$.